# Does running the 'find' command fork a new process?

Tags: unix, process, find

When I type `find` in unix a shell, is a new process created (to handle the find operation) or not? And why?

Answer (score 4):

yes, *generally speaking* `find` is not a built-in command so the shell will spawn a new process, by calling `fork()` which will `exec()` the command.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly (probably), but not necessarily.  If you have previously typed:

```
$ find() { :; }
```

then no new process is created when you type `find`.  Instead, the shell will invoke the function, which is a no-op.  However, if you have not defined such a function, have no alias set for `find`, and an executable named `find` exists in your `PATH`, then the shell will (almost certainly) fork a new process.  ("Almost certainly" because it is quite possible that you are using a shell which implements `find` as a builtin, although I am not aware of any shells which do.)

Comment: +1 for the only answer so far that does not make the mistake of ignoring aliases or functions.

Answer (score 2):

all external commands create process(i.e uses fork()).Ex.find,grep,cp,mv etc.
 only internal commands did not use fork()(ex. cd,pwd etc).Even in some famous books internal commands are defined as the command which does not generate any process.

Answer (score 1):

You also asked *why* a new process is created.

Running a program on Unix involves replacing the memory image of the current process with the image of the program; this is done by the `exec()` family of system calls. When the program finishes, the process terminates. If we hadn't forked a new process, there would no longer be a shell process running to display a new prompt and let you run more commands.

So the shell forks a child process, and this child execs the program. Meanwhile, the original shell process waits for this process to terminate. Or, if you end the command with `&`, the shell doesn't wait -- this is how we run programs in the background (I'm simplifying greatly, but this is the important gist).